# How do you debug Android's watchface?

Tags: android, watch-face-api

For some reason, I can't seem to output anything in Logcat for the watchface example that you can pull from Github's repo. I've enabled the development features in the watch emulator. I have the latest Android Studio. When I start a brand new project, I can output to Logcat without a hitch. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but in case somebody is still coming across this looking for an answer:

I assume you're talking about Googles [Watchface](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/WatchFace) example?

That example uses `isLoggable` to write to the logfiles, for example:

```
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
    }
```

As you can read in the documentation for [Log.isLoggable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html), the `isLoggable` function is basically just a method of customizing/optimizing your log messages, and returns `false` by default.

If you want to enable logging on DEBUG level you can do this via command line with this shell command:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.NameOfMyActivity DEBUG
```

Hope this helps.